# In memoir how to change title-style of a new environment?

Tags: sectioning, memoir

Using the "memoir" envirnmenon I would like to have the same title-style for my chapter as for example "conclusion and outlook".
For my chapter I use the code

```
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1pt \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{60\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
      {
        \scshape \large \@chapapp{} \thechapter
      }
    \par\bigskip\nobreak
    \interlinepenalty\@M
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth+4em]{\Huge \itshape \thickhrulefill~\raisebox{-.5ex}{#1}~\thickhrulefill}}\par\nobreak
\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@ }}
```

to create the following style

[image: chapter title]

However when I would like to generate the same style for other section generated like this

```
\newenvironment{ConclOutl}%
{\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\vfill\begin{center}%
\bfseries Conclusions and Outlook\end{center}}%
{\vfill\null}
```

[image: other title]

How can I uniformize the styles? (I suppose it's rather simple, just change the above code, but I don't really know how and attempts where inconclusive...)

Comment: Why aren't you simply using `\chapter` or `\chapter*` (unnumbered)? Do you need a *concludions and Outlook*-section multiple times? How do you want to use this environment?

Comment: The starred version of \chapter, does not give the special lay-out but again the default chapter-style...

Comment: So the intention really is to get the starred chapter with the unstarred look, except for the *Chaper number* line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the chapter head for unnumbered chapter quite similar, but need to leave out the *chapter number* line. I added

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1pt \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{60\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \par\bigskip\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \makebox[\linewidth]{%
            \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth+4em]{\Huge
                \itshape
                \thickhrulefill~\raisebox{-.5ex}{#1}~\thickhrulefill}
            }\par\nobreak
            \par\nobreak
            \vskip
            40\p@
        }
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
        \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}
    }
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{60\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        {
            \scshape \large \@chapapp{}
            \thechapter
        }
        \par\bigskip\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \makebox[\linewidth]{%
            \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth+4em]{\Huge
                \itshape
                \thickhrulefill~\raisebox{-.5ex}{#1}~\thickhrulefill}
            }\par\nobreak
            \par\nobreak
            \vskip
            40\p@
        }
    }
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Lazy Lizard}
    \blindtext[20]
    \chapter*{Sassy salamander}
    \blindtext[20]
    \end{document}
```

[image: anneonymenMemoirChapterhead]

Comment: Perfect! Still one question, how can I make it appear in the table of contents although I'm using a starred \chapter?

Comment: For all, or just selected?

Comment: Updated. lalallala